# Using sed to replace value in ini config file

Tags: sed

My config file looks like:

```
KEY1=VALUE1
URL=https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=myhash
KEY3=VALUE3
```

I'm trying to use `sed` to replace the URL value with another one. I got to the following:

```
sed -i.bak 's@URL=.*@URL=https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=mynewhash@g' file.txt
```

But that doesn't seem to work, as I'm getting:

```
URL=https://drive.google.com/uc?export=downloadURL=https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=mynewhash=myhash
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&` is a special character in the replacement string provided to the `s` command of `sed`. It represents the string that matches the entire `regex` used to search (`URL=.*` in your example).

In order to represent itself it needs to be escaped with `\`:

```sh
sed -i.bak 's@URL=.*@URL=https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download\&id=mynewhash@g' file.txt
```

Type `man sed` in your terminal to read its documentation or read [the documentation of `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) online.

Comment: Oh didn't know that, thanks. Since we're already here - I've got the new URL as a bash variable - how can I escape it and use it as the substitute second parameter?

Comment: That's another question. That question, similar to this question, has probably already been answered on SO. Anyway, in order to expand the parameter you must enclose it in quotes (`"`) not apostrophes (`'`) and for the escaping you can use [search & replace in the parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).